# Print an object value from a twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

The below object, named 'profile' is available to me in a twig template. I can dump the variables with `{{ dump(profile) }}`. How do I print the 'created' timestamp? I've tried every variation of code I can think of.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the created value from the entity `profile`:

```
{{ profile.created.value }}
```

or formatted:

```
   {{ profile.created.value|format_date('long') }}
```